# vite+ts+vue3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I use vite+vue3+ts to develop a simple vue program

and my  vite.config.ts like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n'
import path from "path";
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

export default defineConfig({
    build:{
        emptyOutDir:true,
        lib:{
            entry:resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
            name:'app',
            fileName:'app',
            formats: ['cjs'],
        },
        rollupOptions:{
            external:['vue']
        },
        outDir:'../../public/static/js',
    },
    plugins: [
        vue()
    ],
})
```

and create vue app

```
  createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    message: 'Hello Vue!'
                }
            }
        }).mount('#app')
```

[image]

Can someone help me out with this？

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'format' in your vite config isn't correct, cjs only support require and you are using import, this means you work with es modules.

You should go like:

```
  formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
```

[Vite build lib mode](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode)

Hope this works for you !